# qt - how to add additional include directories

Tags: qt

Hi I am trying to create a qt program. Here I need some library file which are in

```
C:\Documents and Settings\prabhakaran\Desktop\ChessServerNew\ChessServerNew
```

I tried to edit the .pro file like

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\Documents and Settings\prabhakaran\Desktop\ChessServerNew\ChessServerNew
```

But, still the qt compiler is saying that it can't find those files. Can anybody help me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, might be because of the classical double quotes miss..

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Documents and Settings\prabhakaran\Desktop\ChessServerNew\ChessServerNew"
```

Try this..

Answer (score 0):

Try with a path without spaces in it, or quote it like suggested below. I think the spaces in "Documents and Settings" are the problem.
Generally, I try to avoid any spaces in my paths, as qmake has problems with it.